# Android : Exclude dependency for the application and use only by the other dependency which is using it internally

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I am working on a project where I have to add XYZ dependency. The XYZ dependency is using `com.google.android.material:material` internally and I have not directly added `com.google.android.material:material` dependency in my app level `build.gradle`

Now when I add XYZ dependency in my project, my UI is messed, because of the `com.google.android.material:material` dependency used by the XYZ dependency.

My question is, how can I exclude `com.google.android.material:material` dependency and use that dependency only by the XYZ internally so that my UI do not get mess.

I know I can exclude the whole dependency by this way:

```
    implementation ("XYZ:1.0.7") {
     exclude group: 'com.google.android.material', module: 'material'
}
```

But this will also remove `com.google.android.material` from the XYZ, I don't want that because XYZ needs this dependency in it's UI. I just want to remove it for my application so that my application's UI keep as it is.

See this:

### Before adding XYZ dependency(UI is as expected):

[image]

**After adding XYZ dependency(UI is messed):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude one class for a dependency jar , by using [jarjar tool](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar) .

[Here](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar/blob/master/jarjar-gradle/example/build.gradle#L88) is an example of how to use

```
ependencies {
        compile jarjar.repackage {
            from ('org.apache.hive:hive-exec:0.13.0.2.1.5.0-695') {
                exclude group: 'net.hydromatic', module: 'optiq-core'
                // transitive = false
            }

            archiveBypass "commons*.jar"
            archiveExclude "slf4j*.jar"

            classDelete "org.apache.thrift.**"

            classRename 'org.json.**', 'org.anarres.hive.json.@1'
            classRename 'org.iq80.**', 'org.anarres.hive.iq80.@1'
            classRename 'org.codehaus.jackson.**', 'org.anarres.hive.jackson.@1'
            classRename 'com.google.**', 'org.anarres.hive.google.@1'
            classRename 'javolution.**', 'org.anarres.hive.javolution.@1'
            classRename 'com.esotericsoftware.kryo.**', 'org.anarres.hive.kryo.@1'
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not able to implement it, giving errors because no proper example found. How can I use this? Suppose I am having a library 'io.supercharge:shimmerlayout:2.1.0' and I want to exclude "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0" then how can I implement this in gradle file?